# Confusing about regular expressions.

Tags: regular-expressions

I am new to regular expressions. Hence, it is a bit confusing to me. If I have a regular expression such that $(AAAA^{*}X)^{*}AAAA^{*}$, does $g=AAAAXAAAXAAAAXAAA$ can be one of the expressions? Also, which of the following is the correct way to express the regex?

1. $(AAAA^{k}X)^{l}AAAA^{m}$ where we fixed value of $k$ first, then
   repeated the bracket $l$ times, in which I can never get the
   expression $g$. eg:$(AAAAAX)^{2}AAAAA=AAAAAXAAAAAXAAAAA$

   or
2. $(AAAA^{*}X)(AAAA^{*}X)...(AAAA^{*}X)AAAA^{*}$ in which I can get the expression
   $g$ that I want. However, I am worried this is the wrong idea of
   regex.

Please help me to understand how to read the regex and express them to have the correct expressions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $AAAXAAAXAAAAXAAA$ satisfies $(AAAA^*X)^*AAAA^*$.

Your second option is correct. Elements of $L^*$ are concatenations of sequences of (potentially different) elements of $L$, so elements of $(AAAA^*X)^*$ are concatenations of sequences of (potentially different) words of the form $AAAA^*X$.

Comment: Thank you @TomKern. Now I am more confident with my understanding of regex.